# How would I extract a GZIP encoded binary file from a raw wireshark stream?

Tags: http, gzip, wireshark

I have a raw HTTPS stream captured via Wireshark. The request and response both contained g-zip encoded binary files. They are in the form octet-stream, and specify accept-encoding gzip.

I would like to mock this request and response object on my own with a node.js, but for this I need to extract the original binary files so I can send them back and forth. Is there any way to extract the original raw BIN from the Wireshark capture?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have access to client and/or server to decrypt TLS? That's step#1

Comment: @RossJacobs Sorry, I am super new to networking-- I have parts of the TLS key from the raw HTTP stream ((the part that says --BEGIN KEY-- )), do I have to get another part of it from my client or server?

Comment: That sounds like the public key. The kind of thing you not be sent in plaintext over the network (i.e. it requires access and setup).

Answer (score 0):

To extract gzip compressed data, you can simply use a gzip library in the language of your choice or the Unix executable `zcat`.  To compress data, use the Unix executable `gzip`.  It's really that dead simple:

```
echo "hello world" | gzip > hello.gz
cat hello.gz | zcat   # or just:  zcat hello.gz
```

This will print `hello world`.